# I am unable to run the recorded script from appium inspector in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, appium, inspector

Logs -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: connectwithfacebook
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: what is your app, Is it  web?

Comment: Its an iOS app, I am trying to automate

Comment: because i use to test an url in safari of mobile i was unable because it's an hybrid app !